# How to configure 'crypto-random-string' in Angular 12 without compilation errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am currently working on a migration project which I need to convert from Angular 6 to Angular 12. The updates went well, and ended up with a single library issue 'crypto-random-string'.

So I created a blank project to test the crypto-random-string feature like below.

imports:

```
import cryptorandomstring from 'crypto-random-string';
```

Component:

```
random = cryptorandomstring({ length: 43 });
```

For the first time I got below error,

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '[root]\node_modules\crypto-random-string'
```

I went through the stackoverflow solutions and github issues and found some fixes for this.

- Installed `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`
- Configured `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` in `angular.json`

```
    "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
            },
          ...
    "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          ...
    }
```

- Configured the `custom-webpack.config.js` in my root directory. (as terminal's suggestion)

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify")
    },
  },
};
```

- And installed the `crypto-browserify` package.

And after that I tried building the project and got the same type of errors for `util` and `stream`.
So I repeated the steps above and finally ended up with the `custom-webpack.config.js` like below.

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
      util: require.resolve("util/"),
      stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
    },
  },
};
```

Now my build is success. I thought everything resolved until I run the `ng serve` command.

Now I am getting the compilation error when run with `ng serve` in the console saying,

```
util.js:109 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4655 (util.js:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.2032 (getOwnPropertyDescriptor.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.5041 (app-routing.module.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.6747 (app.component.html:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module.4431 (environment.ts:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
```

Am I going in the correct way? How to resolve this in a standard way? Where did I make the mistake?